# Proper Acronym Usage With Multiple Plurals

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms

> Given that MOTU -> Master of the Universe - One master of one universe 
>   .
>   Would the following be correct? And if not, what *would* be correct, and how would I answer the plural-plural problem at the bottom?  Again, I'm looking for the multiple plural situation

```
MOTUs -> Masters of the Universe - Two masters of one universe   
MOTUs -> Master of the Universes - One master of many universes   
????? -> Masters of the Universes - Two masters of many universes
```

The usage would be something like-

```
The MOTU has spoken- the master of the universe has spoken  
The MOTUs have spoken- the masters of the universe have spoken  
The MOTUs has spoken- the master of the universes has spoken  
The ????? have spoken- the masters of the universes have spoken
```

Comment: I saw your removed edit. I think you should reinstate it.

Comment: I went back an re-read the question you linked... I've noticed that you removed the duplicate question flag... What made you change your mind?

Comment: The edit which you made and removed.

Answer (score 2):

When you stick an 's' on an acronym, it doesn't stick an 's' on the last word of the acronym, but pluralizes the whole thing. So *POWs* means more than one *POW,* and thus *"Prisoners of War"* and not *"Prisoner of Wars"*.

*MOTUs* is the plural of *MOTU.* so it means more than one Masters of the Universe. It's unclear whether it's two masters of two universes or two masters of one universe. However, for most uses one imagines that this can be deduced from context ... how many universes are there?

Comment: It's an example, replace universe with another noun and you're still stuck with the same conundrum. Masters of the Umbrellas... MOTUs could be Masters of the umbrella OR Master of the umbrellas, but then are you saying that it would also account for Masters of the Umbrellas?

Comment: MOTUs is ***never*** *"Master of the Umbrellas"*. People don't use plurals on acronyms that way.

Answer (score 1):

At a very basic level, the subject-verb agreement could be leveraged:

> The Masters of the Universe *have* spoken

would differentiate itself from

> The Master of the Universe *has* spoken.

Still, if clarity is your goal

> The MOTU have spoken

is perhaps not as clear as

> The MOTU(s) have spoken

or even better yet:

> The MOTU - all of them - have spoken

Comment: "all of them" do you mean all the masters or all the universes? ;-)